# Percent Remaining in Histogram

Tags: tableau-api

I have created a histogram in Tableau and I want to change it to a percent of remaining total.

My data is just 2 columns, Customer_Number and Num_Month_Left (the number of months the customer stayed until canceling their service).  I put the Num_Month_Left into bins and put that bin field in the Columns and the Num_Month_Left in the Rows to give me a histogram.

Instead of the total number for the month I would like to see that number divided by the number of remaining customers.

So, for example, in total there are 10,000 customers that have left.  In Month 1 1,000 of them leave so 1,000/10,000 = 10%.  In Month 2 900 leave, so 900 divided by the remaining 9,000 = 10% again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I may have found it

COUNT([Num_Month_Left])/WINDOW_SUM(COUNT([Num_Month_Left]), 0, 23)